# How to set backgroundimage for view for different iPhone Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background-image, device

This is how set backgroundImage for view.

```
 [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"]]];

 //   BG.png for 320X480
 //   BG@2x.png for 640X960
 //   BG-568h@2X.png for 640X1136
```

For each device do i need to set different images size?

@All
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: no need to set sizes, what you have is fine...

Answer (score 0):

just you set only image name dont give extension. automatic get **image @2x image** **when retina display** just you **simple define name "BG"  not define "BG.png"**

Comment: @mitual For retain its take automatically... for iPhone 5 and above the screen size height increase, does its take BG-568h@2X.png automatically.  do i need to set explicitly for iPhone 5c iPhone 5s and above

Comment: just you make two type of image first is  BG.png /(320X480) second is  BG@2x.png (640X1136) no need to any other size image. both image add on project and you use this image only by name example [UIImage imageNamed:@"BG"];